# Why data are not committed to database while using hibernate JTA implementation?

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions, wildfly, jta

EDIT:

First I would like to thank +Vlad Mihalcea for help. Indeed in hibernate 4 , jboss 9 it doesn't make sense to override transaction factory class and manager lookup class. In order to data be committed to database only what you need is as Vlad say:

```
<property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform"/>
```

Using EJB:
One thing what you have to be carful is that you using ejb3 transactions correctly. Default transactional bound context is @Nonbinding and because of that your transaction is not rolled back because you need to provide on which exception your transaction will be rolled back which makes sense.

Example if you want that all your exceptions are rolled back:

```
@Transactional(value = Transactional.TxType.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackOn = {Throwable.class})
```

Using managed bean works normally as well with UserTransaction resource;

QUESTION WAS:

I'm using c3p0, wildfly 9, hibernate 4.3.

Parts of persistance.xml related to JTA configuration

```
 <persistence-unit name="cuponation-backend-v2" transaction-type="JTA">

    <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode" value="after_transaction"/>
            <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class" value="thread"/>

            <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory"/>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup"/>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session" value="true" />
```

While using UserTransaction in bean:

```
 try {
            tx.begin();
            getDAO().merge(entity);
            // getDAO().getEntityManager().flush();
            tx.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            tx.rollback();
            throw e;
        }
```

on merge, data ware never committed to database.

When i try to manually flush changes i get an exception -> "no transaction is in progress":

```
18:06:38,362 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (default task-20) WFLYEJB0034: EJB Invocation failed on component VoucherService for method public com.cuponation.backend.persistence.entities.GenericEntity com.cuponation.backend.rest.services.VoucherService.update(com.cuponation.backend.persistence.entities.GenericEntity) throws java.lang.Exception: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.BMTInterceptor.handleException(BMTInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.EjbBMTInterceptor.checkStatelessDone(EjbBMTInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.EjbBMTInterceptor.handleInvocation(EjbBMTInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.BMTInterceptor.processInvocation(BMTInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.NonPooledEJBComponentInstanceAssociatingInterceptor.processInvocation(NonPooledEJBComponentInstanceAssociatingInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:100)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:66)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:634)
    at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
    at org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:195)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:185)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:73)
    at com.cuponation.backend.rest.services.VoucherService$$$view130.update(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.invokeAndUnwrap(Reflections.java:434)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:127)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:67)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:100)
    at com.cuponation.backend.rest.services.VoucherService$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$.update(Unknown Source)
    at com.cuponation.backend.rest.resources.AbstractResource.update(AbstractResource.java:340)
    at com.cuponation.backend.rest.resources.VoucherResource$Proxy$_$$_WeldSubclass.update(Unknown Source)
    at com.cuponation.backend.rest.resources.VoucherResource$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.update(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:137)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:296)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:250)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:237)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:356)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:179)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:220)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130)
    at com.cuponation.backend.rest.security.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
    at com.cuponation.backend.rest.providers.URLEncodeFilter.doFilter(URLEncodeFilter.java:55)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
    at com.cuponation.backend.rest.providers.ResourceCleanupFilter.doFilter(ResourceCleanupFilter.java:66)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
    at com.cuponation.backend.rest.multitenancy.TenantResolverFilter.doFilter(TenantResolverFilter.java:73)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
    at com.cuponation.backend.rest.logging.LogFilter.doFilter(LogFilter.java:49)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:72)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:282)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:80)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:172)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:774)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.checkTransactionNeeded(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1171)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1332)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.AbstractEntityManager.flush(AbstractEntityManager.java:459)
    at com.cuponation.backend.rest.services.VoucherService.update(VoucherService.java:238)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.delegateInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:70)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.EjbBMTInterceptor.handleInvocation(EjbBMTInterceptor.java:103)
    ... 116 more
```

However when I use container-managed transactions and autocommit option everything works but that is not what I want, because I don't have control over transactional context.

Problems with container managed transactions and autocommit false:

- While using flush there is no error but data is not committed to database.
- Without flush there is no error but data is not committed to database.

How to properly configure JTA bean-managed transactions (JTATransactionFactory) or container-managed transactions (CMTTransactionFactory) without autocommit in hibernate, jboss ?

Answer (score 2):

You should remove these properties since they make no sense for Hibernate 4:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false"/>
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class" value="thread"/>
<property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory"/>
<property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup"/>
<property name="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion" value="true" />
<property name="hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session" value="true" />
```

You only need:

```
<property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform"/>
```

Comment: I try as you suggested but there is then autocommit true by default which is not what i want. Because if i edit entity A and Entity B in same transaction and entity B fails A is not rolledback.

Comment: Autocommit is disabled by default, and this setting only applies for Driver-managed connections, whereas you use DataSource-managed connections. You just need to wrap all changes in a single transaction.

Comment: +1 Hey Vlad you ware right regarding configuration but i figure out where was bug in the code and not using ejb3 correctly because Transactional requires rollbackOn bounded context in order to know on which exception it should rollback otherwise it was not rolled back because default is Nonbinding, and bean managed transactions works aswell. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to update this answer with your findings and mark it as accepted so that others can benefit from it as well.